# Can't run this code Visual Studio (still work in another IDE)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
main() {
    int x;
    char str[80];
    cout << "Enter a number and a string:\n";
    cin >> x;
    cin.getline(str, 80); //take a string
    cout << "You have entered:\n";
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

It will show the error: There were build error https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXOKT.jpg

I was try it on onlinegdb, it can run normally. I try create a new project  in VS and put the code in but it still not worked

Comment: For one you don't use "visual studio" but "visual studio code" two different environments.
First fix your compiler errors/warnings. Unrelated : really stop using `using namespace std;`. Learn to type std:: (in bigger projects you can/will run into issues if you don't do this). Also instead of `char str[80]` use `std::string str;` and use `std::cin >> str;`

Comment: No, I'm sure that I'm using visual studio bro.

Comment: Sorry I see it now, it is visual studio.

Comment: What are the compiler errors you get, because visual studio is complaining there where errors.

Comment: https://imgur.com/jY8tYoA
It just shows that error

Comment: It is common on stackoverflow NOT to use images. But copy source code + errors in your question. Copy code to question then select it and use ctrl+k to format. And that image doesn't even show the compiler errors just that something went wrong. (So we can only help if you show something like `1>C:\Temp\Temp.cpp(9): error C4716: 'operator+': must return a value`)

Comment: From the Solution Explorer part of the screenshots, it seems like the compile errors are from other files, not from `test.cpp`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm do not know what to post, should I copy all text in the output?
https://imgur.com/KZtNmRd

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can view the compile errors by going to `View` -> `Error List` in the menu bar.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed that by adds "int" before "main"

Comment: You might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

That's a small problem. In C++, we shoule always write int main().

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x;
    char str[80];
    cout << "Enter a number and a string:\n";
    cin >> x;
    cin.getline(str, 80); //take a string
    cout << "You have entered:\n";
    cout << x << endl;
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

This will solve the error.

And we can use string instead of char[].

Comment: Sorry I was new here so I didn't notice the c++ tag there. I have edited the post.